# javascript error in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hello I'm using following code for checkbox to close some type of time picker, the code works fine in chrome but not works in Mozilla Firefox. While running on Mozilla Firefox we got the following error, please suggest me some alternative so that it works in both browsers.

Error: closeMonday is not defined

and the code is:

```
<div class="checkbox" name="closeMonday" style="height:16px;float:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;margin-right:5px;display:block" onclick="onClickChangeValue(closeMonday.checked);">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the onclick to:

```
onclick="onClickChangeValue(this.checked);"
```

The word `this` is reserved in JavaScript to describe the "current" element for example in click events, the element being clicked, so this is what you should use.

Chrome is probably "smart" enough to search the document for real element with such name or ID  but you should not count on such behavior.

Comment: be notes that this object reffer to a div so the div is not a checkbox

Comment: @Marwan - I guess he's using custom attributes which is fine. Raman - I'm glad it's working. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - no no I'm thanking to you, its your code which helps me to work. thanks once again.

Comment: Cheers, in such case feel free to Accept the answer as correct by ticking the V icon to the left. :)

Comment: Chrome installs the global scope polluter (the thing that makes `window.closeMonday` be that `<div>` element) on all pages.  Firefox only does that in quirks mode.